# How can I process Apple pay in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, applepay

It's my first time to use apple pay. I'm using react-native-payments library and I could get paymentToken but I cant understand how I can perform a payment process.
The payment provider companey **hyperpay** provided me **entity Id** and **Access token** but I don't know how to use them, which information I'll send, for any link I will send information and which response I'll get. This is the function does Payment process as documentation mentioned

```
paymentRequest.show()
 .then(paymentResponse => {
   const { paymentToken } = paymentResponse.details;  

   return fetch('...', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: {
      paymentToken
     }
  })
.then(res => res.json())
.then(successHandler)
.catch(errorHandler);
});
```

Comment: Please have a look here https://medium.com/enappd/implement-apple-pay-in-react-native-apps-dec9cd5c6808. It helped me a lot

Comment: Thank you for replying
I tried this tutorial and applied the code. My problem is miss-understanding of apple pay itself. How can I use this section:

        .then(paymentResponse => {
          // Your payment processing code goes here

          paymentResponse.complete('success');
        });